# 3-point correlation function for a massive scalar field

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I am a little bit perplexed as to how to compute the three-point correlation function for a massive scalar field, I know that it should be equal to zero.

I need to show that: $\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty (1-i\epsilon)} \int D\phi \phi(x_1) \phi(x_2) \phi(x_3) = 0$

How to show this?

Edit: I forgot to mention without using the generating founction, $Z[J]$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're in free field theory, right? In this case there's a discrete $\mathbb{Z}_2$ global symmetry which takes $\phi\to -\phi$. Applying this to your path integral gives that the three point function is equal to its opposite, so it must be zero. This also holds for interacting theories as long as each term in the interaction potential contains an even amount of $\phi$'s, e.g. $V(\phi)=\phi^4$.

P.S. You forgot the path integral weight $\exp(iS)$ in your formula.